# Finding all positions of an object in an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

My goal is to find the locations of specific image on other PNG image, using python. Take this example:

[image: subimage]

[image: image with dots]

I want to find the coordinates of all dots in the image. The images of the dots is known. Since it's PNG without background color, it would of course be even better not to have the pictures of the dots to find the spots (Of course only if possible without).

At the moment I can only find one spot from a dot. But then unfortunately, not randomly somewhere, but always according to the order of the pixels.

[image]

My working Code (See image above when spot found):
I'm looking for that particular point with the image of the point (subimage), in the image with points.

```
def get_coordinates(canvas, image, _browser):
    canvas_base64 = _browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);", canvas)
    canvas_png = base64.b64decode(canvas_base64)

    with open(r"canvas.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(canvas_png)

    canvas_seats = Image.open('canvas.png')
    i_size = canvas_seats.size
    seat = Image.open(image)
    w_size = seat.size
    x0, y0 = w_size[0] // 2, w_size[1] // 2
    pixel = seat.getpixel((x0, y0))[:-1]

    best = (1000, 0, 0)
    for x in range(i_size[0]):
        for y in range(i_size[1]):
            i_pixel = canvas_seats.getpixel((x, y))
            d = diff(i_pixel, pixel)
            if d < best[0]:
                best = (d, x, y)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas_seats)
    x, y = best[1:]

    draw.rectangle((x - x0, y - y0, x + x0, y + y0), outline='red')
    draw.ellipse((x - 2, y - 2, x + 2, y + 2), fill='blue', outline='blue')
    canvas_seats.save('out.png')

    return [x, y]

def diff(a, b):
    return sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(a, b))
```

How would I go about finding the points in the image? Ideally all of them, otherwise I would be satisfied with just finding a specific one but placing it randomly and not always the same place with every run.

Thanks!

Comment: In this picture I had only one example with one point found. In the image where these dots are found, there are often many of them of different colors.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do at all? Find the dots of the spots? Your image seems to be a massive empty area and there's a red box and a solid cyan circle and an unfilled dark blue circle but no indication of what any of this labelling (or is it the actual image) means? If you are looking for something, please provide that thing on its own if possible. If your image normally contains lots of these things please also provide such an image in addition. Thank you.

Comment: Is `diff()` a function you wrote? If so, can you include the definition?

Comment: @NickODell yes here:
def diff(a, b):
    return sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(a, b))

Answer (score 0):

You can use template matching. Save your images in jpg file format. The first one is your main image and the other one should be the template:
[image]

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv.imread('img.jpg')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv.imwrite('res.jpg',img_rgb)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You can find the coordinate of those boxes based on `cv.rectangle` parameters:  the top-left corner, and the bottom-right corner.

Comment: The code doesn't work for me, it doesn't go into the for loop because the zip(*loc[::-1]) is empty.

Comment: @Agan The code is fine. you can check it here:https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html . you may read the images improperly, or their format is still png, or the path to the images is incorrect.

Comment: I've tried everything, with jpg, png and the path to the images is 100% correct and on your screenshot I see exactly the result that I need.